# Center Align mega dropdown menu with parent parent

Tags: jquery, css, html

I did sometime back create a menu menu with some help from here.  Menu is fine but i need to center align submenu of dropdown & triangle to center of the Parent menu.

I tried few changes to css but it doent work fine I can use fixed value if all parent menu have same with, but that is not the case. I am not sure how to modify script of css to show all the dropdown menus center aligned with respect to their parent menu. I am adding same image also.

Fiddle example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yuvaraj_b/wPWDm/21/)

Some CSS change i made

```
.dropdown ul li:first-child > a:after
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 80px; /* Changed this to 80px */
top: -18px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 8px solid #E5E5E5;
opacity:1.0;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}


.dropdown {
display:none;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:100%;
background:#E5E5E5; 
border-left:0px solid #008438;
border-right:0px solid #008438;
border-bottom:0px solid #008438;
border-top:0px solid #008438;
padding:0 10px;
margin-left:-50px;  /* Changed this to -50px */
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wPWDm/40/show/)**

**CSS updates **

```
.dropdown ul li:first-child > a:after { 
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: -18px;
    margin-left: -5px;
}

.dropdown > ul {
    width: 160px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
}

.nav li:hover .dropdown {
   display: block;
   left: -43px;
}
```

Comment: check your 'Menu four &long' dropdown in your demo. Its out of order.

Comment: @Pravin, It breaks the  `Menu Four & Long`  as it has also moved to right, I want same for this menu also, Anyways appreciate your response..

Comment: @James and KnowledgeSeeker thanks guys yes you are right left: -43px; on .nav li:hover .dropdown causing trouble basically this is calculated as half of parent li width which needs to be calculated dynamically as per width

Comment: @Pravin, is their a way we can calculate this value dynamically